# How To Get A <SAMLAssertion> from <SAMLResponse> With OpenSAML library?

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I am looking for the java code which will read SAMLResponse and retrieves SAMLAssertion to send further ahead. I found http://sureshatt.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-read-saml-20-response-with.html this link which reads SAMLResponse, but not sure whether it really doing the job of retrieving SAMLAssertion only which I want.

Anybody please provide me java test / sample java code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Open SAML library (The OpenSAML-J library provides tools to support developers working with the Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML).)
The maven dependency for your reference below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Once you get the SAMLResponse (which will be an encoded string), using Open SAML you can decode it using Base64 decoder, once you decoded, you need to Unmarshall response and element respectively. Once it's done then you need to type cast to Response Object and from Response Object you get the Assertion. So this assertion will be contaning NameId, Issuer, Audience, Signature etc.

```
//Casting the response to the SAML 2.0 Response message.
Response response = (Response) responseXmlObj;
```

I hope this what the your original query is and I've used the same code from your provided link and it's working fine.